# JavaFX. Draw a ball and drag a line from its center

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

The idea is to draw a ball on MOUSE_CLICKED
And draw a line starting from its center till it released in the MOUSE_DRAGGED handler. 
but it does complete opposite and I do not simply get it - it draws first a line and after i release the mouse the ball appears. 
Does anyone see where is the problem?

```
public class Step extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Canvas layer1 = new Canvas(500, 500);
        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(layer1);

        Ball c_ball = new Ball(0, 0, 50, 0, 0);
        Arrow arrow = new Arrow(0, 0, 0, 0);

        layer1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                ev -> {
                    c_ball.x = ev.getX();
                    c_ball.y = ev.getY();
                    arrow.start_x = ev.getX();
                    arrow.start_y = ev.getY();
                    GraphicsContext gc = layer1.getGraphicsContext2D();
                    gc.setFill(Color.DARKCYAN);
                    gc.fillOval(c_ball.x - c_ball.size / 2, c_ball.y - c_ball.size / 2, c_ball.size, c_ball.size);
                });

        layer1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED,
                ev -> {
                    GraphicsContext gc_arr = layer1.getGraphicsContext2D();
                    gc_arr.clearRect(0, 0, layer1.getWidth(), layer1.getHeight());
                    gc_arr.strokeLine(arrow.start_x, arrow.start_y, ev.getX(), ev.getY());
                });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

Here is class Ball :

```
public class Ball {
public double x, y;
public double dx, dy;
public double size;


public Ball(double x, double y, double size, double dx, double dy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;

}}
```

And arrow

```
public class Arrow  {
public double start_x, start_y;
public double end_x, end_y;

public Arrow(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    this.start_x = x1;
    this.start_y = y1;
    this.end_x = x2;
    this.end_y = y2;
}}
```

Comment: Can u provide `Ball ` and `Arrow ` classes ?

Comment: @aKilleR added those to the description

Comment: I could solve this exact problem, but if you want multiple lines, it wont work. If you want I can post the code as answer. Now it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/vkwBW. After it draws the first ball-line pair, and tries to draw another the line disappears due to `clearRect`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED documentation you will see :

> EventType javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED
>
> This event occurs when mouse button has been clicked (pressed and
>   released on the same node).   This event provides a button-like
>   behavior to any node. Note that even long drags can generate   click
>   event (it is delivered to the top-most node on which the mouse was
>   both pressed and released).

The mouse event you are looking for is `MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED` but in the case your code is not going to work neither. The reason is you clear everything inside the MOUSE_DRAGGED event, when you call `gc_arr.clearRect(0, 0, layer1.getWidth(), layer1.getHeight());`.Thus you will draw the circle but you will clear the canvas and only draw the line. If you remove that line you will have multiple lines each time you drag your mouse but that's a different problem.

You will need to make a big step back and think, do i really need to implement my program with Canvas?

If the answer is **YES** you will need to keep inside a list (or some data structure like array etc) all the components and when you want to change something you need to update the objects and redraw everything

If the answer is **NO** then you are taking the correct approach and you will need to change the canvas to an AnchorPane or Pane etc and just add the Nodes ( Circle , Lines etc ) directly on the pane.

Here is a simple example with AnchorPane instead of Canvas.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShapesTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private double arrayStartX;
    private double arrayStartY;
    private AnchorPane root;
    private Line l;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        root = new AnchorPane();

        root.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, ev -> {
            addBall(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            arrayStartX = ev.getX();
            arrayStartY = ev.getY();

        });

        root.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, ev -> {
            if (l == null) {
                addLine(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            } else {
                l.setEndX(ev.getX());
                l.setEndY(ev.getY());
            }

        });

        root.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, ev -> {
            l = null;
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    private void addLine(double x, double y) {
        l = new Line(arrayStartX, arrayStartY, x, y);
        root.getChildren().add(l);

    }

    private void addBall(double x, double y) {
        Circle c = new Circle(x, y, 15);
        c.fillProperty().set(Color.DARKCYAN);
        root.getChildren().add(c);
    }
}
```

In the example above you could keeps the Circle and the Lines informations on your own custom object if you like and then apply physics on each ball when the mouse is released.

Comment: Nevertheless you are probably on the wrong track with your approach. The Canvas is not the right concept for such interactive drawing. Why didn't you use the scene graph?

Comment: @JKostikiadis I though i need to use canvases as layers, cause later there will be many balls bouncing around on the background but i still have to draw on the upper layer new ones, without interfering (stopping the bouncing on the background).

Comment: @mipa  the plan was somehow to clear the new ones from the upper layer and add those to the bouncing balls on the back...but that is only an idea, dont know if it can work that way

Comment: I understand your point but still this will be a huge headache with Canvas trust me. Just adding the nodes on a pane and manipulate their properties ( width, height , position etc) will be much easier. You can add new one easily when using a Pane, all you need to do is to not consider collisions between the 'background' balls and the balls you are about to add.

Comment: @mipa I have update my answer with a small example, maybe you could use it as a start of your own implementation. I hope it will be useful.